# iOS -- initializing a UIButton forces iAd to dissapear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, iad

I have a strange problem. iAds work. As soon as I initialize a UIButton (using "`[self initCloseAdButtonWithFrame:_frame];`") The iAds stop working, while the button is initialized in the correct place. This code slides an ad banner in and out depending on the availability of the ad.

Why is the initialization of closeButton breaking the ads functionality?

ViewController.m

```
#pragma mark - Ads

-(void)initiAdBanner
{

    DLog(@"");


    if (!self.iAdBannerView)
    {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 0, 0);
        self.iAdBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        self.iAdBannerView.delegate = self;
        self.iAdBannerView.hidden = TRUE;
        [self.view addSubview:self.iAdBannerView];
    }
}




#pragma mark - ADBanner delegate methods -

// Called before the add is shown, time to move the view
- (void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    DLog(@"iAd load");
    [self hideBanner:self.gAdBannerView];
    [self showBanner:self.iAdBannerView];
}

// Called when an error occured
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    DLog(@"iAd error: %@", error);
    [self hideBanner:self.iAdBannerView];

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

    [self.gAdBannerView loadRequest:request];
}







#pragma mark - Banner hide and show -

// Hide the banner by sliding down
-(void)hideBanner:(UIView*)banner
{
    if (banner && ![banner isHidden])
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideBanner" context:nil];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        banner.hidden = TRUE;

        if(closeButton){

            [closeButton setHidden:TRUE];
        }

    }
}

// Show the banner by sliding up
-(void)showBanner:(UIView*)banner
{
    if (banner && [banner isHidden])
    {
        CGRect _frame2 = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        CGRect _frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        [self initCloseAdButtonWithFrame:_frame];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"showBanner" context:nil];
        banner.frame = _frame2;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        banner.hidden = FALSE;


    }
}

//button initialize


-(void)initCloseAdButtonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    DLog(@"");

    closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [closeButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(inAppPurchase)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIImage *_closeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"closeButton.png"];

    UIImage *closeImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:_closeImage.CGImage scale:_closeImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];

    [closeButton setBackgroundImage:closeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [closeButton setBackgroundImage:closeImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(frame.size.width - closeImage.size.width, -5 + self.view.frame.size.height -frame.size.height - closeImage.size.height, closeImage.size.width, closeImage.size.height);

    [self.view insertSubview:closeButton atIndex:2];
    [closeButton setHidden:FALSE];
}

-(void)inAppPurchase{

    DLog(@"");

}
```

ShowBanner is called via a delegate of iAd. In Show banner, the button is initialized. The code works (ads show up) only if the button is not initialized.

In particular, everything works fine until the button is added to the subview.

Comment: adding the button to the subview makes the ads dissapear

Comment: This question has nothing to do with ad mob, that tag should not have been placed in the question.

Comment: I disagree, notice the code: self.gAdBannerView -- gAdBannerView is admob

Answer (score 0):

The issue is  - you are using the same frame to show button and the banner. As a result, the button is covering it fully. Reduce `_frame.size.height` inside `showBanner` function and you will see the banner.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer but I don't think that's the problem -- I am not directly framing the button with the frame of the banner. Instead I am using the coordinates of the banner to decide where I place my button (I offset the button from there). The same problem occurs if I use random CGRect, say {10,10,10,10}.

Comment: checked the image size? Play with scale values from 0 to 1.

Comment: Yeah the image size is fine too. The problem is when I add it as a subview. No matter what size it is, or where it is, iAd disappears. Also I haven't tested this on a real device. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Instead of self.view insertSubview:closeButton atIndex:2 - try addSubView.

Comment: yeah, I tried that. Didn't work. It's the synonymous to adding subview at index:0 I think. But I tried it explicitly too